# implementing masking in python Astropy tables

Tags: python, astropy

Two related questions about implementing masking in a large table.

I am working on a large Table with 50+ columns (merged from different sources). The missing values the columns are either NaN, 0, or empty. I would like to create a mask to find those values and use the same missing value for all. I cannot find a way to do without creating masks for each column.

astropy.table.Table also allows for displaying a sortable table in a web browser using:

```
t.show_in_browser(jsviewer=True)
```

It would be great to display the missing values as blank or '--'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you read http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/masking.html ?  Each column in the table is a separate Numpy array with its own associated mask.  There's no one mask array that covers the whole table (this is because different columns can have different types/shapes/etc.).  But you can easily just loop over the columns to assign masks.

Comment: As for better handling of masked values in the HTML table, there's a pull request for that under review: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/4052

Comment: Right. Looping over the columns! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what @iguananaut said.  E.g. assuming your current table is named `dat`:

```
dat = Table(dat, masked=True)  # Convert to a masked table
for col in dat.columns.values():
    col.mask = np.isnan(col) | (col == 0.0)
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "empty", but the above code should get you started.

As far as I know a masked table will be displayed correctly with the JSviewer output (with `--` for missing elements), it just cannot be sorted.